# Is this a promotion or a test?

Tags: work-experience

I'm a newly employed Frontend developer on six months of probation as a consultant, now I'm reaching 3 months, my manager recommended me to another project of same company I work where he sees me in a better position because he believes I'm a person who likes to explore and learn new technologies and this new project uses new technologies, for example, Angular 4.
I would like to be sure if this is a chance I should take or what does this mean? since I'm still in probation period and I learned a lot in my team in last 3 months, will this be a wise move or I should continue until the six months end then take new challenges?

Thank you for answers and recommendations.

Comment: The description seems to be not matching the title. I read this post 4 times, I cannot see either a promotion or a test anywhere.

Comment: Your manager recommended you to another project. Are you asking us how you should answer?

Comment: Hi guys,Sorry if my description was ambiguous, I was asking if I should take this as an opportunity for gaining more experience?

Comment: @phpguy If your boss has assigned you to that project, I guess you would usually not have a choice to decide whether you should work on it or not, regardless of whether you see it as an "opportunity".

Comment: @MaskedMan he recommended me not assigned me directly :)

Comment: @phpguy What difference does it make what it is called? Your manager wants you to work on that other project where he thinks you can contribute better, so it is the same as telling you to work on that project.

Comment: @MaskedMan No difference, but since I'm on probation period that what worried me :) Thank you for following up and answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is neither a test nor a promotion - this is simply an assignment. Your boss has perceived a need on a project which you seem to fulfil because of your skills and temperament.

However, if you decline the assignment, you may find you will not pass probation, or may be overlooked for other interesting projects in future.

Grab the opportunity before you.